# Регулярное выражение - заменить в группах

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Как в C# с помощью регулярных выражений можно заменить что-либо в группах найденного? Пример: в строке надо заменить запятые (,) на точки с запятой (;) только в скобках.

```
string text = @"магазин Продукты, магазин Запчасти (эмали, лаки), магазин Автотовары (запчасти, комплектующие, разборка)";
```

Шаблон для поиска у меня такой: `@"\((.*)\)"`. Выбрать группы я могу. Как потом заменить и собрать в одну итоговую строку?

Comment: `Regex.Replace`, регулярное выражение кстати не совсем правильное

Comment: как вы пытаетесь менять?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) с параметром `MatchEvaluator evaluator`.
Кроме того, в данном случае нужно использовать ленивый поиск, иначе в первой группе будут все символы между первой скобкой в строке и последней скобкой в строке.

Пример

```
string text = @"магазин Продукты, магазин Запчасти (эмали, лаки), магазин Автотовары (запчасти, комплектующие, разборка)";
string pattern = @"\(.*?\)";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, (m) =>
{
    // возвращаемое значение вставляется вместо обнаруженной группы
    return m.Value.Replace(",", ";");
});
```

Comment: `(m)` необязательно заключать в круглые скобки, а регулярное выражение лучше заменить на `\([^()]+\)`.

Comment: @stribizhev, чем лучше новая регулярка? кроме того что она не пропустит "(a,b(,c)"?

Comment: У меня как раз так и вышло: между первой и последней скобками тоже заменилось... Ленивый поиск?

Comment: @egeo знак `?` после `*` говорит чтобы использовался не жадный алгоритм поиска, когда ищется максимально длинная строка соответствующая выражению